# How to modify values of JsonObject

Tags: java, json, scala, gson, jsonpath

I want to add a new field to jsonObject and this new field's name will be based on a value of another field. To be clear, this an examples of what I want to achieve.

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "properties": [
        {
          "stat": "memory",
          "data": 8
        },
        {
          "stat": "cpu",
          "data": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "properties": [
        {
          "stat": "status",
          "data": "OK"
        },
        {
          "stat": "cpu",
          "data": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a new field to each json object that will have the value of field "stat" as name.

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "properties": [
        {
          "stat": "memory",
          "data": 8,
          "memory": 8
        },
        {
          "stat": "cpu",
          "data": 4,
          "cpu": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "properties": [
        {
          "stat": "status",
          "data": 0,
          "status": 0
        },
        {
          "stat": "cpu",
          "data": 4,
          "cpu": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to do the following with JsonPath library but for me it's an ugly solution as I will parse the json three times and I do some manual replacements.

```
val configuration = Configuration.builder().options(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL, Option.ALWAYS_RETURN_LIST).build()
val jsonContext5 = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonStr)
val listData = jsonContext.read("$['values'][*]['properties'][*]['data']").toString
      .replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",").toList
val listStat = jsonContext.read("$['values'][*]['properties'][*]['stat']").toString
      .replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
      .replace("\"", "").split(",").toList
// Replacing values of "stat" by values of "data"
jsonContext5.map("$['values'][*]['properties'][*]['stat']", new MapFunction() {
      var count = - 1
      override def map(currentValue: Any, configuration: Configuration): AnyRef = {
        count += 1
        listData(count)
      }
    })
// replace field stat by its value
for( count <- 0 to listStat.size - 1){
     val path = s"['values'][*]['properties'][$count]"
     jsonContext5.renameKey(path, "stat", s"${listStat(count)}")
}
```

This is the result obtained

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "properties": [
        {
          "data": 8,
          "memory": "8"
        },
        {
          "data": 4,
          "cpu": "4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "properties": [
        {
          "data": 0,
          "memory": "0"
        },
        {
          "data": 4,
          "cpu": "4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any better method to achieve this result ? I tried to do it with gson but it's not good handling paths.

This a way to do it with Gson but I will lose the information about other columns since I'm creating another json.

```
val jsonArray = jsonObject.get("properties").getAsJsonArray
val iter = jsonArray.iterator()
val agreedJson = new JsonArray()
while(iter.hasNext) {
    val json = iter.next().getAsJsonObject
    agreedJson.add(replaceCols(json))
}
def replaceCols(json: JsonObject) = {
    val fieldName = "stat"
    if(json.has(fieldName)) {
      val columnName = json.get(fieldName).getAsString
      val value: String = if (json.has("data")) json.get("data").getAsString else ""
      json.addProperty(columnName, value)
    }
    json
}
```

Comment: Even though you mentioned it, use Gson/Jackson if you're looking for an easier alternative. Both are fine at handling file systems. What troubles were you having with Gson? You might want to create an open issue with that specific problem with Gson and get it resolved since it would fix your underlying issue.

Comment: Gson doesn't catch the whole Json, I should for example have another variable that will contain the jsonObject and do the changes but I will lose the information about the field "id" for example.

Comment: Gson could absolutely capture this entire object. This looks like a List (since it seems sorted) that is called 'values' and each object in that list has what I would assume would be an integer or long type, followed by a subsequent collection or even array of objects that contains at minimum, or possibly, 2 values; "data" and "memory" which one is of type int or long, and one is of type String. This looks fairly easily mappable.

Comment: I have edited the issue with code specific for Gson.

Comment: You're not really using Gson "as it's intended", and I use that loosely. You're pretty much just using the internal reader and writer.

Comment: Rather use a "real" Scala json lib. There are plenty of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
private static void statDup(final JSONObject o) {
    if (o.containsKey("properties")) {
        final JSONArray a = (JSONArray) o.get("properties");
        for (final Object e : a) {
            final JSONObject p = (JSONObject) e;
            p.put(p.get("stat"), p.get("data"));
        }
    } else {
        for (final Object key : o.keySet()) {
            final Object value = o.get(key);
            if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                for (final Object e : (JSONArray) value) {
                    statDup((JSONObject) e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It seems good to me, I will adapt it to my scala Code and  tell you if it works.

Comment: That works perfectly for net.minidev.json. I'm trying to make it work for gson. Thank you so much for you solution.

Comment: It worked also for Gson, I will post it too.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gson, what you should do is create a base class that represents your initial JSON object. Then, extend that class and add the additional attribute(s) you want to add, such as "stat". Then, load the JSON objects into memory, either one by one or all together, then make the necessary changes to each to encompass your changes. Then, map those changes to the new class if you didn't in the prior step, and serialize them to a file or some other storage.

Comment: Thank you for you response, but I don't think I can do it like that because I don't know in advance all the possible values of field "stat".

Comment: Well, what is status based off of? How do you expect to add status otherwise? Could you set the status to some default state?

Comment: I wanted something that could be helpful even if the format of json changes, that's why I didn't Gson at first.

Comment: Yeah that is understandable, and the great thing about Gson is that it has annotations for handling custom JSON so you can specify type, name, etc (if that's what you're referring to by changes).

Comment: All values of field "stat" will be a new field and its value is the value of field "data". So "status" will be added when we will find that "stat" has a value "status".

Comment: I can have up to 300 different values, I can't really create a class and add annotations, thank you for you suggestions.

Comment: Yeah that is understandable, sorry this didn't help eh. Best of luck! I hope this gets solved.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer from Gene McCulley gives a solution with Java and using class net.minidev.json. This answer is using class Gson and written in Scala.

```
def statDup(o: JsonObject): JsonObject = {
    if (o.has("properties")) {
      val a = o.get("properties").getAsJsonArray
      a.foreach { e =>
        val p = e.getAsJsonObject
        p.add(p.get("stat").getAsString, p.get("data"))
      }
    } else {
      o.keySet.foreach { key =>
        o.get(key) match {
          case jsonArr: JsonArray =>
            jsonArr.foreach { e =>
              statDup(e.getAsJsonObject)
            }
        }
      }
    }
    o
  }
```

Comment: Using `asInstanceOf` can hardly be considered as idiomatic Scala

Comment: I changed it to value.getAsJsonArray

Comment: Not everywhere, also `for` for side-effect, not recommended

Comment: I need to know type in advance, I deleted `asInstanceOf` but I kept `isInstanceOf`. What do you suggest in replacement of `for`

Comment: Use match rather than isInstanceof

Comment: Yes thanks I will use `match` instead of `isInstanceOf`. I used also `foreach` instead of `for`.

Answer (score 0):

This is type-safe, a pure FP `circe` implementation with `circe-optics`:

```scala
object CirceOptics extends App {
  import cats.Applicative
  import cats.implicits._
  import io.circe.{Error => _, _}
  import io.circe.syntax._
  import io.circe.parser._
  import io.circe.optics.JsonPath._

  val jsonStr: String = ???

  def getStat(json: Json): Either[Error, String] =
    root.stat.string.getOption(json)
      .toRight(new Error(s"Missing stat of string type in $json"))

  def getData(json: Json): Either[Error, Json] =
    root.data.json.getOption(json)
      .toRight(new Error(s"Missing data of json type in $json"))
  
  def setField(json: Json, key: String, value: Json) =
    root.at(key).setOption(Some(value))(json)
      .toRight(new Error(s"Unable to set $key -> $value to $json"))
      
  def modifyAllPropertiesOfAllValuesWith[F[_]: Applicative](f: Json => F[Json])(json: Json): F[Json] =
    root.values.each.properties.each.json.modifyF(f)(json)

  val res = for {
    json          <-  parse(jsonStr)
    modifiedJson  <-  modifyAllPropertiesOfAllValuesWith { j =>
      for {
        stat  <-  getStat(j)
        data  <-  getData(j)
        prop  <-  setField(j, stat, data)
      } yield prop
    } (json)
  } yield modifiedJson

  println(res)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task is to add a new field to each record under each properties in the JSON file, make the current stat value the field name and data values the new field values. The code will be rather long if you try to do it in Java.

Suggest you using SPL, an open-source Java package to get it done. Coding will be very easy and you only need one line:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =json(json(file("data.json").read()).values. run(properties=properties.(([["stat","data"]|stat]|[~.array()|data]).record()))) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as addfield.splx and invoke it in a Java application as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call addfield()");
st.execute();
…
```